# Pass shared_ptr as pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a C function whose signature is

```
ldap_initialize LDAP_P((LDAP **ldp, LDAP_CONST char *url ));
```

I use it like this

```
LDAP *ld;
ldap_initialize(&ld, "host_name");
```

and it work fine.

I want to change ld to shared pointer like this.

```
  std::shared_ptr<LDAP> ldap(ld, [](LDAP * ld){ ldap_unbind(ld); });
```

and pass to ldap_initialize.

```
ldap_initialize(&ldap.get(), "host_name");
```

But above code does not work. 
Is there any way of passing shared_pointer or unique_ptr as c styled pointer to pointer.

Comment: Deleted the C tag, because this is a straight C++ question.

Comment: what is the signature of `ldap.get()`?  does it return the value of the pointer? in this case the pointer to pointer life time is the time of the call to 'initilalize' and it does not exist after return,.

Comment: He seems to be writing a C++ application that uses a C library so maybe the tag was correct.

Comment: You are trying to take the address of a temporary - of course That does not work. You have to create the shared pointer from a pointer initialized by `ldap_initialize` not the other way round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it backwards. You initialize a raw pointer and pass it to `std::shared_ptr` to manage:

```
auto get_shared_ldap(char const* url) {
  LDAP *ld;
  ldap_initialize(&ld, url);

  if (/*error occured*/) {
    // Consider throwing something
    return std::shared_ptr<LDAP>{};
  }
  return std::shared_ptr<LDAP>(ld, [](LDAP * ld){ ldap_unbind(ld); });
}
```

You cannot assign to the internal state of a `std::shared_ptr`. Which is what you are trying to do in your code sample.

Comment: No std::string? No coffee for you.

Comment: @RickAstley - What benefit does `std::string` give here? There's no ownership semantics to untangle.

Comment: None, I just felt like nagging because the coffee machine is empty.

Comment: @RickAstley It gave you up, it let you down.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing does not work because `ldap_initialize` (from what I can tell) uses the pointer argument to return a value. Yet `shared_ptr.get()` returns a `ld*`. Note this is a copy of the managed pointer, not a reference to it. Therefore the line `&ldap.get()` tries to take the address to a temporary and rightly fails. `shared_ptr` offers no way to get a reference to its internal pointer because allowing outside sources to modify its inards would destroy its safe memory management.

What you want to do is this

```
LDAP *ld;
ldap_initialize(&ld, "host_name");
if (ld)
    std::shared_ptr<LDAP> ldap(ld, [](LDAP * ld){ ldap_unbind(ld); });
else
   // This is up to you
```

The reason this works and is safe is that `ldap_initialize` will return give a valid value to `ld` only on success. You didn't create an `LDAP` outside of it and nothing can throw between the return of `ldap_initialize` and the creation of the `shared_ptr` so you can't get a memory leak. Sure it's a bit more verbose that what you'd hoped for, but you can always mitigate that by initializing inside a function that returns a `shared_ptr<LDAP>`.

Comment: &ldap.get() doesn't create a reference, it gets the address of the underlying raw pointer.